rosdep not selecting expected libs libqt5core5a/libqt5gui5 vs libqt5core5t64/libqt5gui5t64
I am following the ros2 jazzy tutorials and running into an issue with rosdep (maybe). I am on ubuntu 24.04. I have seen no issues through any of the installation, but am having some issues with Rosdep. In the "Creating a workspace" tutorial, in the resolve dependencies section, executing rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro jazzy -y from ~/ros_ws is returning
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y libqt5core5a]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libqt5core5t64' instead of 'libqt5core5a'
libqt5core5t64 is already the newest version (5.15.13+dfsg-1ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  docker-scan-plugin mailcap
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y libqt5gui5]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libqt5gui5t64' instead of 'libqt5gui5'
libqt5gui5t64 is already the newest version (5.15.13+dfsg-1ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  docker-scan-plugin mailcap
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [libqt5core5a]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [libqt5gui5]


Do i need to deal with the diff in library between the expected libqt5core5a/libqt5gui5 and what is selected libqt5core5t64/libqt5gui5t64? I'm guessing some arch difference perhaps? Do i need to update rosdep to ref the correct libs?
Thanks

I also got the same issue. It seems that the packages changed their name so I ran sudo apt purge libqt5core5a libqt5gui5 to remove the old packages. After that, running rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro jazzy -y no longer generates error.
